# Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/oauth/confirm_access' error in Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2

I'm getting the following error in Spring OAuth2:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/oauth/confirm_access' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1237) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

By debugging in Spring impelmentation I noticed that it is hardcoded this view name. Shouldn't it be implemented in Spring? I suppose I shall not build that view and is just a matter of configuration. 
My OAuth2 authorization server and resource servers are properly configured, so I skiped that part.

Is there a configuration that handles this view?

Thanks.

P.S I am using Postman client to generate token.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem. 
The client should have autoApprove flag set on true.